# Efficient Count of Related Models in Django

Tags: python, django

In my Django app, when I add the `host_count` field to my serializer to get the number of hosts for each domain, the performance of the API response suffers dramatically.

- Without `host_count`: 300ms
- With `host_count`: 15s

I tried adding 'host_set' to the prefetch_related method but it did not help.

Would an annotation using Count help me here?  How can I optimize the fetching of this value?

**serializers.py**

```
class DomainSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    org_name = serializers.CharField(source='org.name', read_only=True)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    last_host_search = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    host_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_host_count(self, obj):
        return Host.objects.filter(domain=obj).count()
```

**views.py**

```
class DomainList(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        domains = Domain.objects.prefetch_related('org').all()
        serializer = DomainSerializer(domains, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**models.py**

```
class Domain(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_host_search = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=settings.MAX_CHAR_COUNT, blank=False, null=False)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Org, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to count the related objects in the same query:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class DomainList(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        domains = Domain.objects.prefetch_related('org').annotate(
            host_count=Count('host')
        )
        serializer = DomainSerializer(domains, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

In the serializer, you then simply retrieve the corresponding attribute:

```
class DomainSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    org_name = serializers.CharField(source='org.name', read_only=True)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    last_host_search = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    host_count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
```

This will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT domain.*, org.*, COUNT(host.id)
FROM domain
LEFT OUTER JOIN org ON domain.org_id = org.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN host ON host.domain_id = domain.id
GROUP BY domain.id, org.id
```

Comment: Thanks!  This fixed my problem.